# Getting started on a stream interface driver

Tags: c#, windows-ce, platform-builder

I want to build a stream interface driver for testing purposes but I am completely lost. I don't know which IDE to use VS2008 or Platform Builder. Platform Builder is whopping 20GB to download :( Can anyone guide me on how i create the .dll file and include XXX_Open, XXX_Close, XXX_Write, XXX_Read in the dll file? Should i write the .dll file in C++ or can i write it in C#? Please guide me through the basics :)
Thanx a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Platform builder 6 is not 20GB as far as I know. It is shipped on one DVD (aside from Visual Studio 2005) so it cannot exceed 9 Gb in the worst case.

You can read [A Stream Interface Driver Shell](https://web.archive.org/web/20200804032513/http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2008/06/09/windows-ce-a-stream-interface-shell.aspx) as a start. You can also find many other posts on the same blog that are extremely helpful and are for the beginner level.

As far as I know writing drivers is done in C/C++. I have not seen an implementation in C# and I don't think it is possible to do so.

---

Here is the link for the Platform Builder download: [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100907190201/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=7e286847-6e06-4a0c-8cac-ca7d4c09cb56) - it states it is 3.8 GB. Of course you need to download VS2005 first.

Comment: I tried downloading Platform Builder from MSDN AA and it was 20GB :(
But thanx a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Drivers *must* be written in C.  They can be written with Platform Builder *or* Visual Studio.  You can only use live debugging of a driver with Platform Builder.

Comment: Would you please tell me what type of project should I choose to write a driver?

Comment: It's a simple Win32 Smart Device DLL.

Comment: You could write the drivers in C++. You only need the xxx_ functions to have the `extern c` declaration